# Setting datepicker by code in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How can I set a datepicker by code

xaml code

```
<toolkit:DatePicker  Name="datepicke1" Header="DatePicker" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ValueChanged="datepicke1_ValueChanged" >
    <toolkit:DatePicker.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:DatePicker.HeaderTemplate>
</toolkit:DatePicker>
```

code behind: (i have date="23-01-2014")

```
void setdatepicker(String date)
{
    // ???

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to set the date:

```
public void setDatePicker(string date){
   datepicke1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(date); // I used the name of your datepicker
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, have a look at this one which explains the programmatic way of adding a `DatePicker` with the use of `Toolkit`.

[Create DatePicker control programmatically](http://transoceanic.blogspot.be/2011/08/wp7-create-datepicker-control.html)

[Programatically launching DatePicker](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/f846cded-90e8-4859-89c1-d67124b8b532/programatically-launching-datepicker)